# asp.net submit button close Jquery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery

I am working on an asp.net page where I have used JQuery UI dialogue. This dialogue has a submit button. When I click the submit button dialogue closes. I want to call a Webmethod on it. If method returns ture, then I want to close it otherwise I want to keep it open with error message shown.

[Edited]

```
    <script>

        jQuery(function () {
            var dlg = jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
                draggable: true,
                resizable: true,
                show: 'Transfer',
                hide: 'Transfer',
                width: 320,
                autoOpen: false,
                minHeight: 10,
                minwidth: 10,
                beforeClose: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetResult",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response == true) {
                                ("#dialog").close()
                            }
                            else {
                                alert('asdasdds');
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    return false; //this will stop dialog box to close
                }
            });
            dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });

    </script>

 <div id="Result">
        Click here for the time.</div>
    <div id="dialog" style="text-align: left; display: none;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnButton_Click" />
    </div>
```

how to do it. Please suggest.

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call webmethod using `ajax` and then act on it conditionally based on the response. Let your webmethod just return `true/false` and then you can check this value on the client side.

Execute this code on submit button click and do not close the dialog. Let the success handler decide whether to close it or no.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "urlOfTheService.asmx/methodName",
    success: function(response){
        if(response == true){
            //Code to close the dialog
        }
        else{
            //Show the error message
        }
    }
});
```

`ajax()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**Update:**

Use `open` event of dialog box to attach the submit handler to form and execute the above code.

```
        jQuery(function () {
            var dlg = jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
                draggable: true,
                resizable: true,
                show: 'Transfer',
                hide: 'Transfer',
                width: 320,
                autoOpen: false,
                minHeight: 10,
                minwidth: 10,
                open: function(){
                     $(this).find('form')
                     .unbind('submit')
                     .submit(function(){
                          var $form = $(this);
                          $.ajax({
                             url: "urlOfTheService.asmx/methodName",
                             success: function(response){
                                if(response == true){
                                   //Submit the form
                                   $form.unbind('submit')[0].submit();
                                }
                                else{
                                   //Show the error message
                                }
                           }
                         });
                         return false;
                     });
                }
            });
            dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. how to use this code with jquery UI's dialog ?

Comment: You have to basically execute this code when you click on submit or close button to close the dialog box. Where is the code to close the dialog box?

Comment: It will have a form for login ( a form, two textboxes and submit button and a link for forgotpass ... when user will click forgotpass, login form will close and frgotpassform will open without dialogue close)

Comment: Show when you submit this form the dialogue box closes because the whole page is refreshed right? Or you have to a code to explicitly close the dialog box?

Comment: it should close automatically. I used above code and it is not working. I pasted the code in question.

Comment: My question is, how does the dialog box close at present? Is there any code to close it?

Comment: Updated the answer, try that.