# How can I get my Popup to close on submit button from AJAX call in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that lists a bunch of items. I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks on the "Action Event" for one of these items (from a table row), a pop-up will appear. The user can then update same information about this item, and either submit the information or close it. Regardless of which option they choose, I'm trying to get the pop-up window to close.

I'm 90% there, I just can't seem to work out one little detail - closing the popup after the submit button is pressed! A lot of the solutions I have seen don't appear to be working, and I just seem to be having some trouble tweaking them to work with my issue. Given the following code, what changes do I need to do to make this work?

Here is what I have:

**View**

*Index.cshtml*

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align="right">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail" data-id="@item.AID">Action Event</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="myModalContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Database/Edit';
        $(function () {
                $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
                        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
                        var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: { "Id": id },
                                datatype: "json",
                                success: function (data) {
                                        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                                        $('#myModal').modal(options);
                                        $('#myModal').modal('show');                   

                                },
                                error: function () {
                                        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");                    
                                }
                        });
                });
        });

</script>
```

**Popup View**

*Edit.cshtml*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AID)
        <table>
        <tr>
         <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment)</td>
         <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "5" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave"/></td>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     </div>
}
```

**Controller**

*DatabaseController.cs*

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.ActionableEvents.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ActionableEvents actionableEvents = db.ActionableEvents.Find(id);
        if (actionableEvents == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(actionableEvents);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AID,Comment")] ActionableEvents actionableEvents)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(actionableEvents).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(actionableEvents);
    }
```

I did see this resource here: [asp.net submit button close Jquery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251034/asp-net-submit-button-close-jquery-ajax), but I'm just not seeing how I would be able to tweak this into what I've got going on right now.

The cancel button I have right now works perfectly. Is there some way to use data-dismiss for my submit button and have it still save the data like I have for the cancel button? I've also seen some solutions use an onClick() parameter in the submit button, but then it would use a window.close() option. I don't want the entire window to close, nor do I want the user to be prompted about it either.

What is a good way I can approach this problem? I want my submit button to work just like my cancel button, only save the data. Thanks in advance for any advice!!!

Comment: I notice you're using `Html.BeginForm`, so how do you post the modal data without refreshing the page ? Usually `Ajax.BeginForm` is used to post forms without refreshing the page. That is important if you want to bind an event on form's post success.

Comment: Well, before, rather than a pop-up the page was an actual View. When the user clicked Save, it would redirect from the controller. In fact, you can still see the RedirectToAction("Index") call in the controller. Obviously, once I have this popup implemented, I won't be calling this RedirectToAction. Is there a better way I can post my data? Not sure how I could use Ajax.BeginForm to solve this, but I'll start looking in the mean time.

Comment: Yes, i would do the following `@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id="_id"})` and then have a jquery function that `preventsDefault` that fires once submit button in the form is clicked. In here you could then hide/ toggle the modal

Comment: JamesS, I'm a bit confused on how I can hide/toggle the modal. Working from my pop-up view (Edit.cshtml), I changed the @using to match what you posted. I then used a jquery to preventDefault() once the button is clicked (again, in my Edit.cshtml file) as per your recommendation. However, I don't understand how I can toggle the modal. Is this something I would need to do back in my Index.cshtml file? If so, how can I have my pop-up view communicate with my Index.cshtml file to toggle the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of playing around, I was able to come up with the following solution:

**View**

*Index.cshtml*

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    <tr>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ActionAway(@item.AID)">Action Event</button>
            </td>
    </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Action This Event</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    var ActionAway = function (theid) {
        var url = "/Database/Edit?id=" + theid;

        $('#myModalBodyDiv1').load(url, function () {
            $('#myModal1').modal("show");
        })
    }

</script>
```

**Pop-up View**

*Edit.cshtml*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AID)
        <table>
        <tr>
         <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment)</td>
         <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "5" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave"/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     </div>
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            success: function () {
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

The controller I was able to leave as it was without making any changes. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try the following in your `Index.cshtml` (make sure you set an id for the form and correct it below):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
   $('#modal').modal('toggle');
});
```

If you want to make an AJAX request to the server and save the data you can do as follows (just include the code below in a click event on the dismiss button from the modal):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveData",
    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (result) {
        // do something
    },
    error: function (result) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

And have a MVC action similiar to:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveData()
{
    // save data
}
```

**Edit**:
After a second reading of your question, you need to make `Edit.cshtml` a partial view, then on `Index.cshtml` include your partial view in the div for the modal like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            @Html.Partial("_EditView")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your JS should look like this:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    e.preventDefault();

    formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SaveData",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData ,
        success: function (result) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (result) {
            // do something
        }
    });

    $('#modal').modal('toggle');
});
```

The JS should be in the `Index.cshtml` because that's where your partial exists, try it and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, iamdlm! I'm still a bit unclear on how I would put this code in my Index.cshtml file.The form itself is actually contained in the Edit.cshtml file, so shouldn't this code also be in that Edit.cshtml file? Also, I'm not particularly set on using AJAX - I'm fine for whichver is the easiest approach. AJAX is the only thing I could get working that would allow me to have a pop-up that uses a view. I'm willing to work with anything, as long as I can get a pop up that loads a view, which can in turn be used to edit data for that row and save it (without reloading the page).

Comment: See my edit. You'll need to make a partial with the content in Edit.cshtml and include the JS in the Index.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I'm still having a few issues - for creating the partial view, right now I just have <div id="EditPartial">, but what exactly would I put between my <div> tags to render the partial view as a poup? Also, your AJAX code utilizes $("form").submit. However, the form is still inside my partial view. How can this be referenced from my Index.cshtml? I know how to communicate with @{Html.RenderPartial), but not sure how I'd handle this with a popup. Sorry to keep struggling with this!!!

Comment: You don't need that div, see my updated edit. You just have to copy paste it basically.

Comment: iamdlm, thank you very much for your help! I was able to get it working today, though I used a different solution than what you posted. I appreciate you taking the time to help me! I have posted the solution I ended up using.

Comment: Glad to help you!